# Why is my alert always showing the wrong information? (addition)

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button, alert

I'm currently writing some code using both HTML and Javascript. I'm building myself a mini Javascript calculator that can run simple additions using a HTML 'GUI' - if you take it that way. The code is below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link href="stylesheet/calculator.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script>
    function activeButton() {
        if (document.getElementById("radioAdd").checked === true) {
            var valueOne = Number(document.getElementById("number1".value));
            var valueTwo = Number(document.getElementById("number2".value));
            var result = valueOne + valueTwo;
        alert("Your Result Is " + result);
        }       
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
        <div id="form-move">
            <form name = "calculator" id="calculator">
                <div id="numberInput">
                    <input type="number" name="inputNumber1" id="number1" placeholder="Type or Select Your First Number" />
                    <input type="number" name="inputNumber2" id="number2" placeholder="Type or Select Your Second Number" />
                </div>
                <div id="radio-input">
                        <span class="title">Operators:</span>
                    <input type="radio" name="radioInputAdd" id="radioAdd" value="Addition" />
                        <label for="radioAdd">Addition</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="radioInputAdd" id="radioDivision" value="Division" />
                        <label for="radioDivision">Division</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="radioInputAdd" id="radioMultiply" value="Multiplication" />
                        <label for="radioMultiply">Multiply</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="radioInputAdd" id="radioSubtract" value="Subtraction" />
                        <label for="radioSubtract">Subtract</label>
                </div>
                <div class="submit">
                    <input type="submit" value="Enter" id="submit" onclick="activeButton()" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
</div>
```

There are TWO input boxes in the middle of the page, which only accept numbers. 
Underneath them are four radio buttons - Add, division, Multiply and Subtract. Now, You can see the javascript incorporated at the top of the page.
 The problem I have is that when I run the page and want to add two numbers, the code works but the answer comes out as 0. I have tested this in chrome and this happens all the time.

Could Someone Possibly please help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is in how you're trying to get the value from the input elements. In this code:

```
var valueOne = Number(document.getElementById("number1".value));
var valueTwo = Number(document.getElementById("number2".value));
```

You're trying to get the `value` property from the *string* `"number1"`, which is `undefined`, then passing that to `document.getElementById`, which will return `null`, and then passing that to `Number`, which will return `0`.

Try this this instead:

```
var valueOne = Number(document.getElementById("number1").value);
var valueTwo = Number(document.getElementById("number2").value);
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
var valueOne = Number(document.getElementById("number1").value);
var valueTwo = Number(document.getElementById("number2").value);
```

You have the paranthesis in the wrong place.